# Change the Player's model in Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to change the model of the player for a mod I am creating for MC 1.10. I have already tried several things and nothing had worked. I already made a model  and renderer, but can't get it to replace the player. Here's what I tried (The custom model is called Hover Claws (Long story)):

```
RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler(EntityPlayer.class, (IRenderFactory)RenderHoverClawsFactory.INSTANCE);
```

Also:

```
public class RenderCustomPlayerEvent
{
    RenderHoverClaws render = new RenderHoverClaws(Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderManager(), new ModelHoverClaws(), 1F);

    @Subscribe
    public void renderCustomPlayer(RenderPlayerEvent.Pre pre)
    {
        pre.setCanceled(true);
        render.doRender((EntityLiving) pre.getEntityLiving(), 0D, -1.625, 0D, 0F, 0.0625F);
}

}
```

I have looked throughout this website, as well as the minecraft and forge forums.

PLEASE HELP!

EDIT: I already looked through the source code for the Morph mod by IChun, and I couldn't find how it changed the player model. If you answer this question by saying that I should look at this mod, then please also direct me to the part of the code that had the actual player model change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest you don't because many mods and models depend on the player looking like he does, stuff is carefully aligned to look good that way.

```
RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler(EntityPlayer.class, new IRenderFactory(){@Override
                public Render createRenderFor(RenderManager manager) { 
                    return new RenderPlayerRobotABC(manager,new ModelHoverClaws(), 0.3F);
                 }
            });
```

Where your model is RenderPlayerRobotABC() derevived from RenderPlayer class.

Take a look in the forgeSrc for RenderPlayer, copy ALL the code, then change what's needed.

Then, render the player model and add your hover claws as a layer.

```
protected void setDamageLayer() {
    this.addLayer(new LayerRenderer(){
        @Override
        public void doRenderLayer(EntityLivingBase player, float par2, float par3,
                float partialTicks, float par5, float par6, float par7, float scale) {
            RenderTools.bindTexture("textures/entity/player/hvoerclaws.png");
            claws.setLivingAnimations(player,par2,par3,partialTicks);
            claws.render(player, par2, par3, par5, par6, par7, scale);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldCombineTextures() {
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

Some critical parts are dependend that all the fields/methods are accessible, so make sure they are :-)

Comment: I don't think you understand. I am trying to **completely** override the player model.

Comment: Then also overwrite the player model net.minecraft.client.model.ModelPlayer contents, modify that, and use that as your main render model...

Comment: First of all, ModelHoverClaws is a polar bear. That is what I want the player to look like. Second, I can't extend RenderPlayer, because It extends RenderLivingBase<AbstractClientPlayer> and passes modelBiped to it. Therefore, I can't change the model.